# EmguCV does not load images from camera

Tags: c#, emgucv

with this simple c# code I am trying to just open camera

```
ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
        viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
    });
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

the result:

[image]

so what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It seem like your camera `drivers` are not properly installed. Try to re-install your camera `drivers`.